# Mongoose connects then disconnects immediately (Node.js + Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an Express (Node.js) app connected to MongoDB using Mongoose.
For the past weeks it has been working fine, but in the last few days it's been driving me crazy.

The server seems to connect to MongoDB then disconnect immediately.
From the `global` log:

```
2015-11-10T15:47:02.083+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:33994 #178 (2 connections now open)
2015-11-10T15:47:02.084+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:33995 #179 (3 connections now open)
2015-11-10T15:47:02.084+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:33996 #180 (4 connections now open)
2015-11-10T15:47:02.085+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:33997 #181 (5 connections now open)
2015-11-10T15:47:02.085+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:33998 #182 (6 connections now open)
2015-11-10T15:47:02.465+0000 I ACCESS   [conn178] Successfully authenticated as principal server on MY_DB_NAME
2015-11-10T15:47:02.466+0000 I ACCESS   [conn179] Successfully authenticated as principal server on MY_DB_NAME
2015-11-10T15:47:02.466+0000 I ACCESS   [conn180] Successfully authenticated as principal server on MY_DB_NAME
2015-11-10T15:47:02.466+0000 I ACCESS   [conn181] Successfully authenticated as principal server on MY_DB_NAME
2015-11-10T15:47:02.466+0000 I ACCESS   [conn182] Successfully authenticated as principal server on MY_DB_NAME
2015-11-10T15:47:02.475+0000 I NETWORK  [conn178] end connection 127.0.0.1:33994 (5 connections now open)
2015-11-10T15:47:02.475+0000 I NETWORK  [conn179] end connection 127.0.0.1:33995 (4 connections now open)
2015-11-10T15:47:02.475+0000 I NETWORK  [conn180] end connection 127.0.0.1:33996 (3 connections now open)
2015-11-10T15:47:02.475+0000 I NETWORK  [conn181] end connection 127.0.0.1:33997 (2 connections now open)
2015-11-10T15:47:02.475+0000 I NETWORK  [conn182] end connection 127.0.0.1:33998 (1 connection now open)
```

You can see it's all from the same second.

How I connect:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://MY_USERNAME:MY_PASSWORD@127.0.0.1:27017/MY_DB_NAME');
mongoose.connection.on('open', function (ref) {
  console.log('Connected to mongo server.');
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
  console.info('Error: Could not connect to MongoDB. Did you forget to run `mongod`?');
  console.log(err);
});
```

The server logs `Connected to mongo server.`.
Where could this be coming from?

I did a fresh install and it's the same so I guess it must be my code.
Is there any other pieces of code I should paste?

Thanks for any help guys.

---

Following Jameson's advise, I changed `mongoose.connect` to `var appCon = mongoose.createConnection(url)`. Checking the logs, that actually does seem to make the connection stick. Weird.

`.connect` obviously isn't the source of this issue. I don't have enough information about it.

How can I check "under the hood"?

---

Well.. This is embarrassing. I've actually left a `mongoose.connection.close();` at the bottom of one file from when I wanted the connection to be dynamic and only open when I need it.

This actually took 3 days to find. What a waste of time!

Thanks for your time guys.

Comment: Why are there five connections all on different ports ?

Comment: I honestly don't know

Comment: @Jaco the default connection pool size is 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
var appConnection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/bookAPI');

appConnection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
appConnection.once('open', function callback () {
    console.log("h");
});
```

Comment: That seems to not disconnect immediately. How can I pass it around files though?

Comment: @Neta `createConnection()` and `connect()` only differ in that `createConnection()` allows for multiple databases.  it will be available under `mongoose.connections[index]`, and you'll have to register each model to that specific connection. There is a different issue that's happening, and using `createConnection()` really just leads to annoyances.

Comment: I marked your answer correct as it did lead me to the answer (along with @cdbajorin's comments) and I wanted to thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: @Neta I'm glad that i was able to help out just a bit :)